# C# Changing sytem locale

Tags: c#, console-application, locale

Need to change the system locale to a different country, I have tried SystemParametersInfo(), GetKeyboardLayout() which didn't help.

How would I change the system locale in C# for a console application?

Comment: are you using winform, wpf, asp.net?

Comment: No Brian am just trying it with a console application

Answer (score 3):

e.g.,

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-AR"); // Espanol - Argentina
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-AR");// Espanol - Argentina
```

e.g,

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // English - US
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");// English - US
```

Comment: I think this will change at the application level but I need to change it at the system level. I mean I have all language packs installed and I want to make the current system locale to a specific locale. Do you have some solution for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SetLocalInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetLocaleInfo(uint Locale, uint LCType, string lpLCData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response bitbonk can you please give an example for suppose to set system locale to fr